# Handling Lack of Property in Some Objects in Array in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, conditional-statements

I have a method wrapped in an observable in one of the components in my Angular 2 app that is designed to filter an array of results depending on the boolean value of a particular property. My method looks like this:

```
    this.clientService.getAllClients()
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
            this.records = resRecordsData;
            this.inactiveRecords = this.records.filter(record => record.registration.active === false);
            this.records = this.inactiveRecords;
        },
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
```

When I run this I get an "undefined" error:

> EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'active' of undefined

I'm assuming this is arising because not all of the entries in the collection contain this property. So my question is, how can I add conditional logic to handle the lack of presence of this property I'm checking against in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check whether the object conains the property first by:

```
record => record.registration && record.registration.active === false;
```

```js
var testItems = [{
  id: 1,
  detail: {
    name: 'test name1'
  }
},{
  id: 2,
  detail: {
    name: 'xxxx'
  }
}, {
  id: 3,
}];

console.log(testItems.filter(function(item) {
  return item.detail && item.detail.name.indexOf('test') > -1;
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if properties are defined on objects by using

```
obj.hasOwnProperty('foo')
```

So in your case you could do something like

```
this.inactiveRecords = this.records.filter(

    record => {

        let registration = record.hasOwnProperty('registration') ? record.registration : false;

        if (registration && registration.hasOwnProperty('active')) {
            return registration.active === false;
        }

        return false; // Default return for when property is not defined.

    }

);
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty